# how to list all files in a given period according their duration(not moment) of access

Tags: awk, find, ls, sort, stat

under linux, how to list all files
in a given directory and its subdirs,
in a given period, say last 10days,
according their duration of access, ideally the result ought to be sorted by access duration ; the duration parameter expressed in hh:mm.ss format

Example:
on a same day, a file F1 has been opened at 12:00:00 and closed 12:30:00, I want 30mins(or 30x60secs) for this one, while if file say F2 has been opened at 12:01:00 and closed at 12:02:00 I want 1 min(or 60sec).

Thanks

Comment: The Linux kernel does not track durations and save them to the filesystem timestamps for `stat()` to retrieve.  Only the last time a write was performed of the contents (mtime), the last time a read was performed on the contents (atime), and the last time the file's metadata was changed (ctime).  If you use an application program which logs file open/close timestamps in its own logfile, then you can parse through that log to learn the durations.  This is unusual for apps unless extensive debug logging is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

That information is not available by default, but you could log from now on **and then** process the result to get what you need.

In theory there are many ways to log it, depending on the processes that access those files, where the files are, if you need that information on a regular basis or you are debugging ...: `inotify`, `auditctl` (linux kernel audit subsystem) come to mind, even `strace` could help you log it.

For a general solution you could use something like:

[LoggedFS](https://rflament.github.io/loggedfs/) is a fuse-based filesystem which can log every operations that happens in it.

In any case, you will be adding a layer of processing and logging, it will impact, at least, performance.

Comment: Thanks, as I understand now, by default there is no standard additional field keeping track of the access' duration, aka any other time tracing than last "CRUD" times do require some software component.

Answer (score 1):

That is not something that the Linux kernel keeps any information of, not something that any filesystem I'm aware of would have a specific field for.

So: what you want is impossible. The information is just not there.